# application of the Savage - Dickey ratio

Tags: self-study, bayesian, likelihood, likelihood-ratio

The Savage - Dickey ratio is an equivalent, but more useable, form for the Bayes factor for two model, model $M_{0}$ and model $M_{1}$.

The definition for the Bayes Factor $BF_{ij}$is as follows:

$BF_{ij} = \frac{p(X | M_{0})}{p(X | M_{1})} = \frac{p(\delta = \delta_{0} | x, M_{1})}{p(\delta = \delta_{0} | M_{1})}$

Problem:

Consider a model with likelihood $L(\theta | x) = 1_{|\theta - x| < 1/2} (\theta)$, prior being $\pi(\theta) = U(\theta | -w/2, +w/2)$.
Let $x = 0, w > 1$. What is the Bayes Factor for the two hypotheses $\theta = 0, \theta \neq 0$?

Attempt:

Based on the above, the likelihood and prior can be explicitly stated to give the model $M_{1}$:

$L(\theta = 0 | x) = 1_{|- x| < 1/2} (\theta = 0)$, $\pi(\theta = 0) = U(\theta = 0 | -w/2, +w/2)$

so that $M_{1} = 1_{|- x| < 1/2} (\theta = 0) U(\theta = 0 | -w/2, +w/2)$.

Any hints to allow me to continue this would be greatly appreciated.